# How to select a value with any characters on multiline using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking to select all `calc()` value in a CSS file.

`calc\(.*\)` works to select the value when it's on one line. But I can't make it on multiline value.

[Here's an exemple](https://regex101.com/r/mJ1eB4/1)

```
h1 {
    font-size: calc( 1rem * 1.26 * 1.26 * 1.26 );
}

h1 {
    font-size: calc( 
                       1rem 
                       * 1.26 
                       * 1.26
                       * 1.26
                   );
}
```

Comment: Can there be nested parentheses inside `calc()`? Like `calc( 1rem * (2 - 2.5))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[\s\S]*?` to match any kind of character (including line breaks).

```
\bcalc\([\s\S]*?\)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mJ1eB4/2)